# Exposé will not stay open on iMac Snow Leopard with "F3" or "Fn +F9"

Tags: macos, mac, expose

When I hit F3 to go to expose (or fn + F9), it pops up for a fraction of a second then disappears again.

I have only had my iMac a week and have not installed anything beyond a couple of widgets and iWork.

I have to hold F3 down to view it - is that normal? I am sure it did not do this before.

Comment: seems to be intermittent, meant to say that

Comment: That's not normal, you should be able to hit the expose key (by which I mean the "all windows" option and have all the windows lined up ready to be chosen from.  Have you tried switching it to a different Fn key? You can do so in the sys pref pane for Expose & Spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has not occured since reboot, and no, I wasn't holiding the key down too long.

Answer (score 1):

You say it seems to be intermittent. This happens for me if I haven't used Exposé for a long time. Then when I pop it up, it's as though it's reading the hard drive pulling Exposé into RAM. In cases like that, I've noticed that OS X interprets short keyboard entries as long ones due to that extra delay in reading from swap. Thus, Exposé only pops up for a fraction of a second. (The same thing would happen if you held down the F3 key for a second or longer, then release.) On the second try, Exposé is fresh in RAM and comes up like it should. Is this what you're experiencing?

I could be totally wrong about what's happening, and this is just my interpretation. Sorry, I have no fix for this.

Comment: Even more: holding down any Exposé button for 1 second or longer will already yield this effect. (So: are you really hitting the key just very shortly?)

Comment: i'm on a quadcore imac with 4gb of ram, with not much running, so i'd be surprised...i am unable to spot a pattern as to why it occurs, it's very annoying though

Comment: @adolf, just to emphasise it a bit: are you very sure you're not holding down the key too long?